# Puppet test defined variable with an empty string

Tags: ruby, automation, puppet

I'm trying to test if a variable has a value with a simple `if` in puppet, but it never reachs the `else` condition that I'm trying to achieve.

ex :

```
if $::some_var['some:name'] != undef {
   $var = $::some_var['some:name']
}
else {
  $var = $::some_var['another:name']
}
```

`some_var` cames from a json file, and if the `::some_var['some:name']` is emtpy it will put `$var` as empty, but what I'm trying to achieve is, if the var is defined but is empty to actually go through the `else`, can this be achieved using for instance

```
if defined($::some_var['some:name']) {
   $var = $::some_var['some:name']
}

else {
   $var = $::some_var['another:name']
}
```

Comment: Yes those conditionals are equivalent. If the desired behavior is still not achieved, then we need some more information to fix the code.

Comment: Hi @MattSchuchard thanks for the answer, I'm testing that locally and it doesn't work as expected, what I'm doing and it's working is something like this.                                  ```$var = ''

if $var =~ String[1] {
notify{"The value is: ${var}": }
}
else {
notify{"The value is: empty": }
}


file {'/tmp/helloworld.txt':
  ensure  => present,
  content => "Hello World!",
}
```

Comment: If I understand correct you want the else branch to run if the variable is undefined or if it is equivalent to an empty string. Have you tried `if defined($::some_var['some:name']) and $::some_var['some:name'] != '' { }else{}`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved it by using

```
$var = ''  
if $var =~ String[1] { 
notify{"The value is: ${var}": } 
} 
else { 
notify{"The value is: empty": } 
}   

file {'/tmp/helloworld.txt':   ensure  => present,   content => "Hello World!", }
```

If I define `$var` whit some value, I'll met the `if` condition, if `$var` is empty I'll met the `else`.